# What is optimum data interval algorithm for Orbit Determination?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, debris, orbit-determination

I am trying to find Optimum data interval algorithm for orbit determination. Because in Leo, Geo orbit updates the **measurement** data can be different so that I want to implement an optimum data interval algorithm for Orbit determination. I found one thing for that **LUPI algorithm** but haven't still found more details about LUPI algorithm. Which kind of algorithm can use in Geo, MEO, Low orbit? Because Atmospheric drag and solar radiation are really important sometimes not need to update frequently the measurements. LUPI algorithm is mentioned in 'Conjunction Assessment Risk Analysis M.D. Hejduk NASA CARA Collision Avoidance “Short Course” Part I: Theory'

Comment: This isn't an answer because I don't know enough about machine learning, but in usual statistical orbital determination, one looks at whether or not the covariance on each of the state components is approaching the SNC noise level of the filter. If no State Noise Compensation is turned on, then you check to see how close to zero the covariance is. If it's "close enough", you consider the filter to have converged to a good solution for that arc.

Comment: The filter is converged at the moment but I am trying to increase of performance of the filter so that I need to apply a algorithm for that

Comment: This question and its answer seem to be related but not a duplicate: [Tracking Arc and Time for Precise Orbit Determination](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6528/12102)

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/43941064?seq=1#page_thumbnails_tab_contents , Space Surveillance Network Optimization (SSNO) Study,” ESC/NDS Technical Report B001-3.1.4-SSNORPT-1,
Colorado Springs, CO, August 2002.  these two papers are explaning but I havent still reached these paper. I have still tried to download but hasnt done yet